# How can I favourite countries from an API with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, api, ionic-framework, frontend

I am working on a COVID-19 statistics app with **Ionic** and **Angular**. The data is retrieved from an API. This is the API: https://covid19api.com/. I can search up for countries but now I want to be able to make a country a favorite using local storage so that next time I don't have to search for a country when I get into the app. I want to be able to favorite multiple countries and make it visible under the h1 title of favorites in a bootstrap card. I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

**search.page.html**

```
 <ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Search</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row class="ion-justify-content-center">
      <ion-col class="ion-text-center" size="10">
        <div class="box">
          <h1 class="title">WORLDWIDE</h1>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Country</label>
            <select (change)="getCountry($event.target.value)" class="form-control">
              <option *ngFor="let country of countries" value="{{country.Slug}}">
                {{country.Country}}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="getCoronaData()">Search</button>
          <br><br>

          <div class="card text-white bg-success mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
            <div class="card-header">Total numbers of COVID-19 cases</div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">Total confirmed cases: {{confirmed}}<br>
                                   Total recovered cases: {{recovered}}<br>
                                   Total death cases: {{deaths}}<br>
                                   Total active cases: {{active}}<br>
                                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">ADD TO FAVOURITES</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div>
          <h1 class="title">FAVOURITES</h1>
        </div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>

</ion-content>
```

**search.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.page.scss'],
})
export class SearchPage implements OnInit {
  private interpretations: [];

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  public data = [];
  countries: any;
  country: any;
  confirmed: any;
  recovered: number;
  deaths: number;
  active: number;

  ngOnInit() {

    this.dataService.getCountries().subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.countries = data;
    });

    this.dataService.getRequest().subscribe((response: any[]) => {
      console.log(response);
      this.data = response;
    }) ;
  }

  getCoronaData(){
    this.dataService.getCoronaSearch(this.country).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      const index = data.length - 1;
      this.confirmed = data[index].Confirmed;
      this.recovered = data[index].Recovered;
      this.deaths    = data[index].Deaths;
      this.active    = data[index].Active;

    });
  }


  getCountry(country: any){
    this.country = country;
  }
}
```

**data.service.ts**

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable, throwError} from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  private API_URL = 'https://api.covid19api.com/world/total';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }

  getCountries(): Observable<any>{
    const url = 'https://api.covid19api.com/countries';
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(url);
  }

  getTotal(): Observable<any>{
    const url1 = 'https://api.covid19api.com/world/total';
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(url1);
  }

  getWorldNew(): Observable<any>{
    const url2 = 'https://api.covid19api.com/summary';
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(url2);
  }

  public getRequest() {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.API_URL).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  public getCoronaSearch(country): Observable<any>{
    const url = 'https://api.covid19api.com/total/dayone/country/' + country;
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(url);
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    let errorText = 'Error';
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // Client side errors
      errorText = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
    } else {
      // Server side errors
      errorText = `Error status: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
    }
    console.log(errorText);
    return throwError(errorText);
  }
}
```

Comment: While it is _great_ that you have included code in your question, this is a _lot_ of code, and I don't see where you have made any attempt to implement the feature mention in your question.  Would it be possible to pare this down into a [mcve] and show what you have tried so far, including what issues you are seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can do something like this if u want to add country to local storage, on html :

```
<ion-grid fixed>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col size="4"></ion-col>
    <ion-col size="4">
      <h1>Country</h1>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let country of countryList | slice:0:5 ;let i = index;">
          <ion-label>{{ country.Country}}</ion-label>
          <ion-icon slot="end" name="add" (click)="addFav(country)"></ion-icon>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="4"></ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col size="4"></ion-col>
    <ion-col size="4" *ngIf="favList.length != 0">
      <h1>Favourite</h1>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let fav of favList; let i = index;">
          <ion-label>{{fav.Country}}</ion-label>
          <ion-icon slot="end" name="remove" (click)="removeFav(i)"></ion-icon>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="4"></ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

on ts file :

```
url = 'https://api.covid19api.com'

  countryList = [];
  favList     = [];

  constructor(
    private storage     : Storage,
    private http        : HttpClient
  ) {
    this.getCountry();
    this.storage.get('FAVLIST').then(fav => {
      if (fav) {
        this.favList = JSON.parse(fav);
      }
    });
  }

getCountry(){
    let url = this.url + '/countries';
    this.http.get(url, {observe:'response'}).subscribe((data:any) => {
      this.countryList = data.body;
      console.log('Country List',this.countryList);
    },(err:HttpErrorResponse) => {
      console.log('Something Went Wrong')
    });
  }

  addFav(country){
    this.favList.push(country);
    this.storage.set('FAVLIST', JSON.stringify(this.favList));
  }

  removeFav(i){
    this.favList.splice(i,1);
    console.log(this.favList);
    
    this.storage.set('FAVLIST', JSON.stringify(this.favList));
  }
```

result :

[image]

here a sample on stackblitz :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-jfmvz5?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are attempting favorites other than

```
<h1 class="title">FAVOURITES</h1>
```

Having functional requirements is essential to any program. Otherwise, how would you know what to do and when the program is complete?

- Get list of countries (Done) Select a country to view the results.
- Add a 'Add Favorite' button to save the currently selected country to
  your favorities. This can be a list of string.
- Once favorited, save the list to your localStorage.
- You should be able to list your favorites using *ngFor
- You should be able to delete from this list to remove a favorite
- Clicking on a favorite should auto-select that favorite to get the latest info
- On page load, pull favorites from localStorage and load them in your favorites section.

Now that you have some basic requirements, try to program some of this out. We're here for you when you have a specific question on one of these steps.